# IoC.BuildUp doesn´t build object

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

I Am very new to Caliburn and have to expand an existing program, using caliburn.micro

I need my DataContext in a View to be set to a ViewModel which has some propertyinjected parameters. All this should work, so i only need to build it up.
however it does not! here is the code where i try to bulid:

```
public ProductionMainView()
{
     InitializeComponent(); 
     var gg = IoC.Get<ProductionMainViewModel>();
     IoC.BuildUp(gg);
     this.DataContext = gg;
}
```

As far as i can understand I need to get the object and then build it.
Now I should get a view "Containing" my ViewModel, but the View is blank,
I hope i have explained myself well enough. 
Best regards

Comment: Why calling BuildUp if the object is being created by Unity itself. Rather use Resolve. Also, What dependencies do you have in ProductMainViewModel object?

Comment: Also, Have those dependecies in ProductMainViewModel are marked with `[Dependency]` attributes?

Comment: not necessary to buildup or set the datacontext.  definitely nothing to do in the constructor of the view either.  Can you post your project or a sample project so we can see what you have done so far.  I having a feeling that your configuration is slightly off... What does your bootstrapper look like?

Comment: @vendettamit i have not used the     [Dependency] as it is not an Unity project

Comment: my Bootstrap looks as follows :
http://imgur.com/yG3J6n4
Sorry for link, not enough characters to post is all

Comment: placed into answer, could just update the original question with the infos next time :)

Answer (score 2):

First off you are using a really old version, present version is 2.0.2, and you still need to have overrides for GetInstance, GetAllInstances, BuildUp methods in your BootStrapper or a variant for use with Ninject

http://putridparrot.com/blog/caliburn-micro-and-inversion-of-control-using-ninject/

Link above has some source for this.

Remember there is nearly no code in the Codebehind of the View... It will all go into the ViewModels (for the most part).  ShellView => ShellViewModel with in ShellViewModel `var gg = IoC.Get<ProductViewModel>()` depending on you are intent is with that you can bind it to a `<ContentControl x:Name="ProductViewModel" />` with a property in yoru viewmodel called exactly that.  CM will go out and fine that ViewModel and associated view and mash them together automagically.  Expected results on the screen should be your ProductViewModel in that contentcontrol location.

```
 public class ShellViewModel : Screen
 {
       private ProductViewModel _productViewModel;

       public ShellViewModel (){


       }

       protected override void OnActivate(){

         ProductViewModel = IoC.Get<ProductViewModel>();
       }
       public ProductViewModel ProductViewModel {
          get{ return _productViewModel;}
          set{
                _productViewModel = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChanged (); // 2.0.2 feature...
          }
      }
  }
```

Now, if you decide to move to the latest version there are subtle changes one `Bootstrapper<T>` does not exist anymore it was refactored into BootstrapperBase.  Next Initialize() will be placed into the ctor of your Bootstrapper().  From there everything will be based on your starting screen is after Initialize() is called in the CTOR you will call `DisplayRootViewFor<ShellViewModel>()` in the OnStartup override.

Some have said and I tend to agree over using `IoC.Get<T>()` can be anti-pattern, caution when using it. Sometimes things change unexpectedly.  Those tend to DI the items via the CTOR and use from there accordingly.

```
/*version 1.52*/
public class Bootstrapper : BootStrapper<LoginViewModel>{

    public Bootstrapper(){

        Start();
    }

    protected override Configure(){

        /* -- your Ninject configurations -- */
    }

    protected override object GetInstance(Type service, string Key){
        if(service == null)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("Service");
       return _kernel.Get(service);
    }

    protected override IEnumerable<object> GetAllInstances(Type service){

      return _kernel.GetAll(service);
    }

    protected override void BuildUp(object instance){
      _kernel.Inject(instance);
    }

    protected override void OnExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        kernel.Dispose();
        base.OnExit(sender, e);
    }

 }
```

To clarify do you have to login to get to the ProductionMainViewModel?  What determines  your logic for getting to ProductionMainViewModel to even display?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers!! 
the
    <ContentControl x:Name="ProductViewModel" /> 
has allready been set. The ProductionManiViewModel is a "masterview" containing serveral views.
The problem however is that the constructor of ProductionManiViewModel which has all the other ViewModels dependencyInjected, is not called right, so the Views are    null
I dont know how to solve this

Comment: said in another way : ProductionMainViewModel isn´t called and i cant figure out how to do that since it has all those property injections.

Comment: I know you showed me your Configure override.  Does your current application run 1.52 or earlier than?  Would there be harm if you were to update to 2.0.2?  That small amount of updates would probably help slightly in the startup flow of your application.  Since LoginViewModel is your starting point in your Bootstrapper that leads me to believe that is your Shell.  That is where `IoC.Get<ProductionMainViewModel>()` would be called to prime that viewmodel with injects.  Something just feels off with your workflow.. Not trying to be negative just need to see more..